# install bacula director / server on windows?

Tags: windows, backup, bacula

Looking over the bacula.org site, I see several places where it implies it IS possible to run bacula director or server on Windows.

I saw mention that the windows client installer should allow it to be installed.  I found some documentation that even shows a 'server' check box for the client installer.   However when I run the windows installer, no server check box and nothing that looks like it is server related...?

I at least would like to be able to run the storage daemon on a windows machine(s).  I could live with the director on linux if I had to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, prior to version 5, it was possible to run all the Bacula components on Windows.

With the release of version 5, those pieces went away.  I'm not sure of the reasoning behind the changes, only that it happened.

It's possible that what you're seeing is old documentation.